# Find unknown mean and standard deviation of a truncated normal distribution

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I'm trying to find out the mean and standard deviation of a lognormal distribution, where not all results are included. It's for a running event with cutoff times. Basically, I'm trying to find the unknown mean and standard deviation of a truncated normal distribution.

[image]

The graph looks like this, with the normal distribution based on the mean and standard deviation calculated from all registered results. But as can be easily seen, the normdist curve is pushed too much to the left, due to the lower mean of the sample than it would be if the entire population was included. Also, I suppose the stdev may be different if also slower results would be included?

Is it possible to calculate the unknown mean and standard deviation of the entire population?